# Azure B2C SSO configuration options differences

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, openid, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to set up the Azure B2C Tenant to provide SSO authentication but I can't figure out what are the differences between the available options:

[image: SSO azure b2c options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you set it to tenant then once a user is signed into one app then they can do a silent log in to any other app on the tenant.

So if you had

app1 and app2 in same tenant

app1 open in tab1 and app2 in tab2 logging into app1 would mean that when you clicked login on app2 then it would do a silent login

application - restricts this to a single application but you can log in to the app on multiple tabs within the same browser.

policy - restricts it further so you would have to call the same policy, so if you had policy login1 and policy login2 then you you only get auto signin if you call the same policy

Disabled - you dont get single sign on

Comment: Interesting enough, we've had an issue whereby setting the configuration to **tenant** made so that we couldn't get a new token after the session expired (60min). For some reason the **Web app session lifetime (minutes)** seemed to be ignored. Changing to **policy** fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Official documenation on [learn.microsoft.com - Single sign-on (SSO) configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso#single-sign-on-sso-configuration)